# Magento- Get Store, website, group Object by Name

Tags: magento, object

I am looking for a way to get an Magento object (store, website, group) by name. Yes, I know that I can get the whole collection and just iterate through it, but that seems rather silly to me. I have tried a number of experiments, but all to no avail. Certainly there must be some way to have the database find this object for me, rather than having to return a whole collection and iterate over it manually.

So far, I have tried such gems of code as the following, all without any luck.

```
$site = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection')->addFieldFilter('name', "Test Website");
$site = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website')->loadByAttribute('name', 'Test Store');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you didn't executed your below code

```
$site = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection')->addFieldFilter('name', "Test Website");
```

cause if you did it will give you below Fatal error and you are able to figure out the problem.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website_Collection::addFieldFilter() in...
```

Anyways use the below code

```
$site = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', 'Test Website');
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return a collection of websites? Most likely a one-item collection, sure, but I'd imagine that to get the actual website object you'd need to add getFirstItem():

`$site = Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', 'Test Website')->getFirstItem();`

Answer (score 3):

Hello check below code may be help you

```
Storeid:-Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
Storecode:-Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
Store Name:-Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();
Website Id:-Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
Store Group Name:-Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getName();
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not quite what I need. I am looking for a way to get the object GIVEN the name. I have an object name (ie, a website name), and I wish to get the related object from the name. Yes, I can get a collection, iterate through it until the name matches. But I was looking for a cool way to find the object given it's name.